# laravel 8 api : delete file from folder when updating post

Tags: php, laravel, api, file-upload

i have posts tables and i upload images for it , so in `update()` method in `PostController()` i want to edit post and images

for editing images , i want to delete last images from folder and database , and replace new images.

so i can delete last images from database but i can't delete them from folder

the controller :

```
public function update(StorePostRequest $request , $id )
    {

        $validatedData = $request->all();

        if ($request->hasfile('image')) {

            $postTitle = $request->title; //post title for folder name and the images inside it

            //delete last Images from database for updating images
            Image::where('imageable_type' , 'App\Models\Post')->where('imageable_id' , $id)->delete();

             $directory =storage_path().'/images/posts/'.$postTitle;
            if($directory){
                Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory('images/posts/.$postTitle');
            }


            $files = $request->file('image');

            foreach ($files as $file) {

                $imageName = time().rand(1,10000).'.'.$file->extension();

                $postTitle = $request->title; //post title for folder name and the images inside it
                $imagePath = public_path(). '/images/posts/'.$postTitle;

                $file->move($imagePath, $imageName);

                $image = new Image;
                $image->image = $imageName;
                $image->path = $imagePath;

                $images[] = $image; // make an array of uploaded images
            }
        }

        $post = Post::find($id);

        $post->category_id = $validatedData['category_id'];
        $post->title = $validatedData['title'];
        $post->body = $validatedData['body'];
        $post->study_time = $validatedData['study_time'];

        $post->save();
        $post->images()->saveMany($images);

        return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "successfully",
        "data" => $post
        ]);
    }
```

the relation between posts and images is : one to many polymorphic and i taste it with postman

i tried this  ways and it doesn't work :

```
             File::delete(public_path('/images/posts/'.$postTitle));

             Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory($directory);
```

in addition , when i try

```
       Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory('images/posts/');
```

it works and the posts folder has been deleted , but the problem is from `$postTitle`

when i use it, doesn't work

Comment: do you want to delete images from the images folder. ? question not clear

Comment: yes , i edit my question .. check it again please

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for delete file

```
if (!is_dir(public_path('/images/posts/'.$postTitle))) {
    mkdir(public_path('/images/posts/'.$postTitle));
}
```

Comment: what is full path your image

Comment: in public folder , i have images folder : `public/images/posts/postTitle` . the postTitle is the folder name and images of a post are in this folder

Comment: try this new code
```if (!is_dir(public_path('/images/posts/'.$postTitle))) {
    mkdir(public_path('/images/posts/'.$postTitle));
}```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete directory use `Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory('images/posts');`

Comment: thanks it works but just for posts folders , i want to delete the postTitle directory in posts directory , ( delete last post images not all of the posts images)

Comment: @dumpAndDie so just add a dir name to end of path like u did `Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory('images/posts/' . $postTitle);`  Or I didn't get it?

Comment: it doesn't work (can't delete directory )

Comment: @dumpAndDie idk, just tested and everything works. Any errors? permissions? May be you running code under apache and have wrong folder owner?

Comment: no there is no problem because the posts folder can be deleted .. i think my way is wrong and for updating images i must try another way to remove last images and replace new images